# Why do penalties improve regression results?

Tags: regression

Here is regression model without penalty:

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \epsilon$$

Here is regression model with penalty:

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \epsilon + \lambda\beta_1^2$$

Here is the error term for the model without penalty:

$$E = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - (\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i))^2$$

Here is the error term for the model with penalty:

$$E = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - (\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i))^2 + \lambda\beta_1^2$$

We can see that the error of model with penalty is bigger than error of model without.

But how do we know that model with penalty has better chances to not overfit data compared to model without penalty? Maybe model without penalty overfits data .... but model with penalty also overfits data AND has higher error.

In this cases, plan backfires to reduce overfitting ... overfitting might not be reduced and on top of that overall error was increased .... here, it would be better to use model without penalty. In other words, model with very low error could be overfitting ... but could also be very good model.

I understand more parameters in model makes lower error (bias variance tradeoff) but this lower error could be deceitful (overfitting) ... penalty term shrinks regression coefficients and thereby indirectly makes simpler model with higher error that is believed to overfit the data less .... but how we can be sure that all this is correct? At the end of day, maybe model without penalty overfits data .... but model with penalty also overfits data AND has higher error?

Comment: Note that the errors come from different models: the parameters of the regularized model will be different than those from the not-regularized one. Also, it is not automatically given that a regularized model will predict better. There are theoretical results that usually involve misspecification of the model (which may or may not be the case, though I would argue that most, if not all models are indeed misspecified). You may want to take a look at chapter 11 in Hastie et al., *Statistical Learning with Sparsity*.